# How to change the height of Kendo ui Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

How do I change the height of the Kendo Grid when using wrappers?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I assume the method you are looking for is under the Scrollable configuration (it is there because one Grid needs to be scrollable if you want it to have height)

```
.Scrollable(scr=>scr.Height(230))
```

Answer (score 44):

To change height dynamically

remove htmlattributes:

`.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:600px;" })`

Add scrollable with auto:

`.Scrollable(a => a.Height("auto"))`

Comment: This works great, but I need a 20px footer at the bottom. How can I do that?

Answer (score 10):

In strongly typed ones use for a rigid fixed height

```
.Scrollable(scrollable => scrollable.Height(100))
```

In Js after dataSource declaration use

```
$("#Grid").kendoGrid({

            dataSource: { },

            height: 450,

            pageable: {
                refresh: true,
                pageSizes: true
            },

            columns:
                [
                   ***
                ]
        });
```

You can also bind your grid for minimum and maximum heights for all the girds you have through css.

```
.k-grid .k-grid-content {
 min-height: 100px;
 max-height: 400px;
}
```

Or you can specify a specific grid, you replace the .k-grid with the specific grid id `#YourGridName`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

`HtmlAttributes()` will let you add attributes to the `<div>` that holds the toolbars, paging, table, etc.

`TableHtmlAttributes()` will let you add attributes to just the `<table>` element

Exmaple setting table to 750px by adding a style attribute:

```
  @Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
               .Name("Grid")
               .TableHtmlAttributes(new {style="height: 750px;"})
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use external css rules for this, which can be preferable if your grid is re-used (as in a partial view). If you provide a style or height attribute, Kendo adds those in-line and thus they cannot be overriden by an external style sheet. Sometimes you want that, but sometimes you don't.

Using the `.Name()` string provided to the wrapper, it's easy to write a css rule to target the header or the content.

```
#GridName .k-grid-content {
    height: 300px; /* internal bit with the scrollbar */
}

#GridName .k-grid-header-wrap tr {
    height: 75px; /* header bar */
}
```

Note that the `.k-grid-header-wrap` class may vary depending on how you initialize the grid. Also, you have to target the `tr` or `th` tags inside the header. Styling the whole header (it's usually a div tag) leads to inconsistent results. Some browsers won't apply the rule, some browsers will leave a visible artifact where the borders of the actual tr/th begin.

Oh, and I should also say that this approach allows flexibility when changing between an MVC wrapper created grid and a regular js created grid. Or you can reuse the style sheet between different grids.