# How to set the height of KendoUI Grid with it's ASP MVC Complete Wrapper

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm using KendoUI Grid with its ASP MVC Complete Wrapper library and I'm having problem setting the height of my grid in the razor code. I tried setting the HTMLAttribute but doesn't seems to work.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SoftInn.Data.Country>()
    .Name("grid-countries")
    .DataSource(datasource => datasource.Ajax()
                                .Model(model => model.Id(record => record.Id))
                                .Create(create => create.Action("Add", "Country"))
                                .Read(read => read.Action("GetAll", "Country"))
                                .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "Country"))
                                .Destroy(delete => delete.Action("Delete", "Country"))
                                .Events(events =>
                                            {
                                                events.Sync("gridcountries_synchandler");
                                                events.Error("gridcountries_errorhandler");
                                            })
                                .PageSize(10)                                   
    )
    .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(r => r.Name);
                    columns.Bound(r => r.Currency);
                    columns.Bound(r => r.TimeZone);
                    columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(170);
                })
    .ToolBar(toolbar =>
                 {
                     toolbar.Create().Text("Add New Country");                            
                     toolbar.Custom().Text("Refresh").Url("#").HtmlAttributes(new { onclick = "window.refreshGrid($(this).parent().parent())", @class = "customRefreshButton" });

                     toolbar.Custom().Text("More").Url("#").HtmlAttributes(new { onclick = "window.toggleDisplay($('#grid-countries > .k-grouping-header'))", @class = "customToggleButton float-right" });                         
                 }
    )
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .Pageable(pageable =>
                {
                    pageable.Refresh(true);
                    pageable.PageSizes(true);
                })
    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
    .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Filterable()
    .Selectable()
    .ColumnMenu()
    .Groupable()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { Height = "400px"})  
  )
```

Comment: Check out for more options:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955673/how-to-change-the-height-of-kendo-ui-grid

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the following:

```
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:400px" })
```

The current setting won't work because `Height` is not a valid HTML attribute for the `DIV` element which the Kendo Grid is rendering.

Answer (score 3):

I know the question is very old but it may help others.

```
 .Scrollable(src => src.Height(230))
```

That will do the trick as well.