# Show fixed # of rows in Kendo Grid even with no data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using 2 Kendo Grids to show some data. When data in the 1st grid is selected, data in the 2nd grid is updated accordingly. These 2 grids are put on a page side by side in a 2-column layout. Now, I set the height of them are the same.

The issue is, usually the 1st grid has more data, i.e. has 10 rows (per page), the 2nd grid has few data, so in most cases, it has 1 or no row data. Because of this, the pagination section of the 2nd grid changes its location. is it possible to always show it at the bottom. For example, if no row, then just show a blank area with pagination section at the bottom?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I'm using Kendo UI for MVC. According to some search, I use: .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 400px" }) , somehow the pagination section does not stay at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

@urlreader, can you share your code on jsfiddle,that helps to identify the issue.I have same scenario in one of my previous tasks and I achieved it using height property of the grid.

Below is the fiddle I created for your reference:
[http://jsfiddle.net/Sowjanya51/s2ajrj09/](http://JSfiddle)

Comment: thanks. how to use this in Kendo UI for MVC? I use: .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 400px" }) , somehow the pagination section does not stay at the bottom, although your example works as what I wanted.

Comment: found solution: .TableHtmlAttributes(new {style="height: 450px;"}) , see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955673/how-to-change-the-height-of-kendo-ui-grid